# How to efficiently create duplicate copies in SAS

Tags: sas

Suppose I have a dataset as follows:

```
ID Col1 Col2 Col3 Value
1   2   5     6    100
2   32  42         999
```

and I want to create a data set as follows:

```
  ID Col Value
   1  2  100
   1  5  100
   1  6  100
   2  32 999
   2  42 999
```

what would be the best way to go about doing this? Note, I have a missing value for Col3 in my original dataset, so I would only want to create new rows where there are no missing values in the columns.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use PROC TRANSPOSE to get the desired output. ID and Value column can be used with BY statement since that defines the group for exapanding value variable.

```
proc transpose data=input_data out=output_data(where=(col1 ne .));
    by id value;
    var col1-col3; 
run;
```

Comment: when I transpose the data set, the resulting dataset contains multiple columns for each of the values but I only want one column. Is there any easy way to specify this?

Comment: the resulting dataset should only contain 4 columns. There would be just 1 extra dummy column _NAME_ that should be extra in comparison to the resulting output data you've provided. Anyway, if you want to drop/keep any column just use the dataset option KEEP= or DROP= just like WHERE= has been used.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use arrays...

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  array c{*} col1-col3 ; 
  do i = 1 to dim(c) ;
    if not missing(c{i}) then do ;
      col = c{i} ;
      output ;
    end ;
  end ;
  drop col1-col3 i ;
run ;
```